# $K$ is a field containing $\mathbb{Z}_p$, then $\alpha\in K$ and $\alpha^p=\alpha$ implies $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> suppose $K$ is a field containing $\mathbb{Z}_p$, then $\alpha\in K$ and $\alpha^p=\alpha$ implies $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}_p$.

I've got a solution by algebraic algebra theory if $K$ is finite generated field of $\mathbb{Z}_p$, but still not sufficient to fulfill the prove when $K$ is infinite, i.e. $K=\mathbb{Z}_p(\pi)$. With the knowledge of elementary number theory, this prob. got difficult to me.

Comment: "Algebraic algebra theory" : seems like a nice topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Over any field, the equation $X^p-X=0$ has degree $p$ and so at most $p$
solutions. But it has $p$ solutions in $\Bbb F_p$, so cannot have any more
in any field containing $\Bbb F_p$.

Comment: yes, factor $x^p-x$ in field $K$ is the key. thx so much.

Comment: @Larry Eppes I respectfully think you're missing the point. You don't need to factor it in $K$. All that matters is that is a polynomial of degree $p$ and thus has at most $p$ solutions in any field.

Answer (score 1):

$ x^p-x$ has degree $p$ so it has at most $p$ roots in $K$.

The set of this  roots is $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Comment: thx, I've got the key.